# ¿Como mostrar dos tablas relacionadas y condicionadas con left outer join?

Tags: php, mysql, select, join

Quiero saber porque no me muestra registros cuando condiciono una consulta

Les muestro dos imagenes en la primera realizo una consulta sin condicionar la materia y si me da todos los registros de la tabla USUARIOS y en la segunda imagen condiciono a la materia y no me muestran registros sobre todo la lista de usuarios, será que deberia crear un bucle para que me haga un registro para poder mostrar condicionando?????? pero igual el left join deberia de dar registros aunque haya WHERE nota.ID_MATERIA

```
SELECT 
us.ID_USUARIOS,
us.USU_FOTO,
us.USU_NOMBRE1,
us.USU_NOMBRE2,
us.USU_APELLIDO1,
us.USU_APELLIDO2,
nota.ID_MATERIA,
nota.NOTA_N1,
nota.NOTA_N2,
nota.NOTA_N3,
nota.NOTA_N4,
nota.NOTA_PROMEDIO

FROM  usuarios us 

LEFT OUTER JOIN notas nota
ON
us.ID_USUARIOS=nota.ID_USUARIO


WHERE 
us.ID_CURSO=14 AND
us.ID_NIVEL=4 AND
us.ID_PARALELO=2 AND
us.ID_ESPECIALI=2 AND
nota.ID_MATERIA=14 AND
us.ROL=0

ORDER BY  us.USU_APELLIDO1 ASC
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
SELECT 
    us.ID_USUARIOS,
    us.USU_FOTO,
    us.USU_NOMBRE1,
    us.USU_NOMBRE2,
    us.USU_APELLIDO1,
    us.USU_APELLIDO2,
    nota.ID_MATERIA,
    nota.NOTA_N1,
    nota.NOTA_N2,
    nota.NOTA_N3,
    nota.NOTA_N4,
    nota.NOTA_PROMEDIO

    FROM  usuarios us 

    LEFT OUTER JOIN notas nota
    ON
    us.ID_USUARIOS=nota.ID_USUARIO
    
    WHERE 
    us.ID_CURSO=14 AND
    us.ID_NIVEL=4 AND
    us.ID_PARALELO=2 AND
    us.ID_ESPECIALI=2 AND
    us.ROL=0

    ORDER BY  us.USU_APELLIDO1 ASC
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No era necesario que borraras la otra pregunta.. bastaba con editarla... Ahora, los dos sql que pusiste aca son el mismo?

Comment: serio, lo siento gracias por instruime, si son diferente los sql @gbianchi

Comment: Entonce no habra ningun registro que cumpla eso...

Comment: entiendo entonces deberia crearle el registro como haria una condicion bucle que me cree el registro si no extistiene para ese USUARIO porque podria luego ingresar un nuevo estudiante @gbianchi

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que SQL ejecuta la cláusula `WHERE` después que hace el JOIN. Primero el `LEFT JOIN` te recupera todos los registros que por lo que muestras en tu ejemplo tienen `ID_MATERIA = NULL`

Después se ejecuta el `WHERE` que te filtra las filas con `ID_MATERIA=14`, por tanto en ese ejemplo no te devolvería ninguna.

Si necesitas que te devuelva todos los registros a pesar de no tener `ID_MATERIA=14` puedes pasar la condición del `Where` hacia el `LEFT JOIN` quedando así

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN notas nota  ON us.ID_USUARIOS=nota.ID_USUARIO AND nota.ID_MATERIA=14
```

Así te devolverá todos los registros, pero, solos las filas que tengan  ID_MATERIA=14 te mostrará valores para los datos de la tabla notas, no sé si eso te sería útil.

Saludos

Comment: Hola un gusto @gcamps , muchas gracias te cuento lo agregue y ahora si me muestra datos de ususarios aunque no hayan registro en notas proveientes de ese curso y esa materia eso es lo que queria, ahora voy a pasar a la fase de enviar datos para que los grabe o los actualice si ya estos ya existieran te mostrare mi avance voy a editar la pregunta dame un momento